# Object does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/client/2009"

Tags: arcobjects, c#, visual-studio, wpf, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

I am trying to move all of my GIS code over the Visual Studio 2012. I have added the following references:

C#:

```
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Geometry;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks;
```

XAML:

```
xmlns:esri="http://schemas.esri.com/arcgis/client/2009"
```

The problem is that many of the objects are not being recognized because they do not exist in the namespace...
Some of these include the InfoWindow and Legend.
However it seems to be OK with objects such as the PictureMarkerSymbol and the Map and Layers.
I don't know if something has changed since I last looked at it, if so I think ESRI need to update their SDK samples.

Comment: perhaps a dumb question, but have you installed the latest ArcGIS API for Silverlight (3.1) and its dependencies (http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/silverlight-api/concepts/index.html#/Installation/016600000005000000/) , and checked that your references refer to its libraries, and not the libraries for an earlier version?

Comment: I have installed the WPF version

Comment: Does the project reference the `ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.dll` assembly?

Comment: That was the problem @PetrKrebs haha. I felt pretty silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your project references the `ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Toolkit.dll` assembly.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably already looked here: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000408000000
This is .Net specific.  If you're developing with silverlight it might be the same. I know there were changes for jscript and one was geometry

Comment: I am using WPF. I looked there but it didn't really tell me what to do differently.